# Join or subtractByKey on 2 huge RDD's

Tags: pyspark, rdd

I am building a recommendation system for retail purposes. I use python and Spark.

I am trying to subtract all user product combinations of my predictions which also occur in the ratings (so I only predict the values of products users never bought before).

Those 2 RDD's are pretty large and are giving me memory issues on 28gb per worker node (3 nodes) when I do

`filter_predictions = predictions.subtractByKey(user_boughtproduct)`

When I read the documentation of Spark subtractByKey is optimal when using 1 large and 1 small rdd.

I cannot make the user_boughtproduct smaller (unless I loop it), but I could make.

`filter_predictions = predictions.join(user_nonBoughtProduct)`

Any thoughts on which of them is faster or best practice? Or another cleaner solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`subtractByKey` pushes filters after co-grouping and doesn't have to touch right values so it should be slightly more efficient than using outer join an filter after flattening.

If you use Spark 2.0+ and records can be encoded using `Dataset` encoders you can consider `leftanti` `join` but depending on the rest of your code cost of moving the data can negate benefits of an optimized execution.

Finally if you can accept potential data loss then building Bloom filter on the right RDD and use it to filter the left one can give really good result without shuffling.

Comment: I see. Any tips on another approach?

Comment: Do you need exact results?